# Difference between increasing function and strictly increasing function in terms of derivatives?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Consider the following theorem and remarks from the **Application of Derivatives** chapter in p. 201 of the [NCERT textbook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8hXbvn1ab-BaXM0YjVhc285Z28/view?resourcekey=0-QLQBstamNZCN-LyLg9dXGQ).

> Theorem:
>
> Let $f$ be continuous on $[a, b]$ and differentiable on the open
> interval $(a,b)$. Then
>
> (a) $f$ is increasing in $[a,b]$ if $f′(x) > 0$ for each $x \in (a,
>  b)$
>
> (b) $f$ is decreasing in $[a,b]$ if $f′(x) < 0$ for each $x \in (a,
>  b)$
>
> (c) $f$ is a constant function in $[a,b]$ if $f′(x) = 0$ for each $x
>  \in (a, b)$
>
> Remarks:
>
> (i) $f$ is strictly increasing in $(a, b)$ if $f′(x) > 0$ for each $x
>  \in (a, b)$
>
> (ii) $f$ is strictly decreasing in $(a, b)$ if $f′(x) < 0$ for each $x
>  \in (a, b)$
>
> (iii) A function will be increasing (decreasing) in R if it is so in
> every interval of R.

I am thinking that the theorem is incomplete and the remarks are correct. That theorem has to be as follows:

> (a) $f$ is increasing in $[a,b]$ if $f′(x) \ge 0$ for each $x \in (a,
>  b)$
>
> (b) $f$ is decreasing in $[a,b]$ if $f′(x) \le 0$ for each $x \in (a,
>  b)$

Since there is a difference between increasing function and strictly increasing function, I am feeling that the theorem given in the textbook is faulty. Am I correct, or where am I going wrong?

Comment: Of course you must use the definition in that book when discussing theorems in that book.  Unfortunately, the definition of "increasing" may not agree between books.

Comment: @GEdgar It is as per standards only. Please check p 199 and p 200 for the definition.

Comment: *I am thinking that the theorem is false* $\ldots$ *theorem has to be as follows* --- I'm confused, because the theorem has a stronger hypothesis and the same conclusion as what you stated. If the theorem is false, then your version -- which has a weaker hypothesis -- must also be false. Also, do you have a counterexample in mind for the theorem being false?

Comment: Normally, functions made by joining several pieces e.g. when from a to b the function is constant for x<a it is strictly increasing and for x>b it is strictly increasing. Tis whole function will be called non decreasing or only increasing (not strictly increasing).

Comment: @ryang Okay. I will read and do accordingly...

Answer (score 1):

> > Theorem:
> >
> > Let $f$ be continuous on $[a, b]$ and differentiable on the open
> > interval $(a,b)$. Then
> >
> > (a) $f$ is increasing in $[a,b]$ if $f′(x) > 0$ for each $x \in (a,  b)$
> >
> > (b) $f$ is decreasing in $[a,b]$ if $f′(x) < 0$ for each $x \in (a,  b)$
>
> I am thinking that the theorem is incomplete and the remarks are
> correct. That theorem has to be as follows:
>
> (a) $f$ is increasing in $[a,b]$ if $f′(x) \ge 0$ for each $x \in (a, 
> > b)$
>
> (b) $f$ is decreasing in $[a,b]$ if $f′(x) \le 0$ for each $x \in (a, 
> > b)$

Indeed, the book's Theorem can be strengthened exactly as you suggest. (But it is not "incomplete"—just weaker than necessary/usual.)

> > Remarks:
> >
> > (i) $f$ is strictly increasing in $(a, b)$ if $f′(x) > 0$ for each $x  \in (a, b)$
> >
> > (ii) $f$ is strictly decreasing in $(a, b)$ if $f′(x) < 0$ for each $x  \in (a, b)$

In fact, the book's Remarks too can be strengthened:

(i) $f$ is strictly increasing in $[a, b]$ if $f′(x) > 0$ for each $x  \in (a, b)$

(ii) $f$ is strictly decreasing in $[a, b]$ if $f′(x) < 0$ for each $x  \in (a,b).$

Comment: If we are going to strengthen the remarks, we could say that $f$ is strictly increasing if $f'(x)\ge 0$ and $f'(x)=0$ only in isolated points. For instance, $f(x)=x^3$ is strictly increasing regardless of the fact that $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: @PierreCarre Nice!